# Relation between sets of solutions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider a non-homogeneous linear system $Ax=b$ with four equations and three variables. Call $(Σ)$ the corresponding homogeneous system. What can we conclude about the general solutions of the two systems, given that $rank(A)=rank([A\mid  b])=2  $ ?

Here's what I've thought so far:
Since $A$ and $[A \mid b]$ have the same rank we know that $Ax=b$ has a solution. 
It can also be proven that if $z$ and $y$ are two solutions of $Ax=b$ these are related by the equation $y=c+x$ where $c$ is a solution of $(Σ)$. I don't know if any other conclusions can be made. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Look up Kernel in linear algebra

Comment: What is the size of $A$? What conclusion do you want to make?

Answer (score 0):

We can additionally specify the *set of all solutions*. In fact, the essence can already be seen when considering the corresponding *homogeneous linear system*.

> Let $A$ be the coefficient matrix of a homogeneous, linear system of equations with $n$ variables
>
> \begin{align*}
> Ax=0\tag{1}
> \end{align*}
>
> The following is valid:
>
> - The set of all solutions is a subspace $U$ of $K^n$, with $\mathop{dim}U=n-\mathop{rank}(A)$.
> - If $\mathop{rank}(A)\neq n$, there are $s=n-\mathop{rank}(A)$ linear independent solution vectors $c_1,\ldots,c_s$ and
>     \begin{align*}
>   x=\lambda_1 c_1+\cdots +\lambda_s c_s\tag{2}
>   \end{align*}
>     with arbitrary $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_s\in K$ is the general solution.

Since in our example the rank of $A$ is two and there are three variables, the set of all solutions is a subspace $U$ of $K^3$ with dimension $$\mathop{dim}U=3-\mathop{rk}(A)=1.$$ $K$ is the underlying field, typically $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$.

So, if we find a specific solution $x=c_1$ of (1), the set of all solutions is given by
\begin{align*}
x=\lambda_1 c_1\qquad\qquad \lambda_1\in K
\end{align*}

> Now, let's consider the *non-homogeneous* linear system of equations $Ax=b$ with $b\neq 0$.
>
> OP has already noted, when solutions do exist ($\mathop{rank}(A)=\mathop{rank}([A\mid b])$) and how different solutions of the inhomogeneous linear system are related. Based upon these facts and (2) we can describe the set of *all solutions* of the inhomogeneous linear system of equations.
>
> Let $A$ be the coefficient matrix of an non-homogeneous, linear system of equations with $n$ variables
>
> \begin{align*}
> Ax=b
> \end{align*}
>
> The following is valid:
>
> - If $s=n-\mathop{rank}(A)>0$ and $B=\{c_1,\ldots,c_s\}$ is a basis of the vector space of solutions of the corresponding *homogeneous linear system* of equations (1), the general solution of the *non-homogeneous linear system* of equations has the form
>     \begin{align*}
>   x=c_0+\lambda_1 c_1+\cdots +\lambda_s c_s
>   \end{align*}
>     with $c_0$ a solution of $Ax=b$ and arbitrary $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_s\in K$.

In our example we see, that the set of all solutions is given by
\begin{align*}
x=c_0+\lambda_1 c_1\qquad\qquad \lambda_1\in K
\end{align*}
with $c_0$ a specific solution of $Ax=b$.